# React Router Content Not Changing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a complete React newbie and am creating a simple site to display Tableau visualizations. I am using React Router.

I have a route for each component and a functional component that is adding the necessary shared JavaScript for Tableau to display. In each component I am using a $.getJSON to retrieve the correct visualization for that component.

The URL is changing correctly, but the content in the view is not. It just stays the same. My understanding of React is probably way off and any help is much appreciated.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import SiteHeader from './SiteHeader';
import Main from './Main';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SiteHeader />
        <Main />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Main.jsx (router)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './views/Home'
import ServiceDashboard from './views/ServiceDashboard';
import Feedback from './views/Feedback'

const Main = () => (
  <main>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/viz/service-dashboard`} component={ServiceDashboard} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/viz/feedback`} component={Feedback} />
  </main>
)

export default Main
```

Tableau.jsx

```
const loadViz = () => {
  let tabViz,
    testWorkbook,
    testWorksheet,
    placeholderDiv = document.getElementById('root');

  let options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '850px',
    hideToolbar: false,
    onFirstInteractive: function () {
      testWorkbook = tabViz.getWorkbook();
      testWorksheet = testWorkbook.getActiveSheet();
      worksheetList = testWorksheet.getWorksheets();
    }
  };

  let parseResponse = function (json) {
    if (tabViz) {
      tabViz.dispose();
    }
    tabViz = new window.tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, json.uri, options);
  };
}

export default loadViz
```

ServiceDashboard.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../shared/tableau';

class serviceDashboard extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON("/tableauServer/myVisualization", parseResponse);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}

export default serviceDashboard
```

I am able to return the visualization if I refresh the page but when going from one page to the next, the visualization does not update with the route. Like going from

```
<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/viz/service-dashboard`} component={ServiceDashboard} />
```

to

```
<Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/viz/feedback`} component={Feedback} />
```

Comment: Take a look in your browser's developer tools console. What errors are there?

Comment: try adding `componentDidMount` code in `serviceDashboard` to `componentDidUpdate` method, and let know about result. And please capitalize name  `serviceDashboard` =>  `ServiceDashboard`, it hearting my eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would you put in ```componentDidMount``` and ```componentDidUpdate```?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your routes on a router/switch component:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <SiteHeader />
          <Main />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Main = (history) => (
  // history comes from withRouter
  <Switch location={history.location}>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/viz/service-dashboard`} component={ServiceDashboard} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/viz/feedback`} component={Feedback} />
  </Switch>
)

export default withRouter(Main);
```

Comment: I get an error ```Line 19:  'Routes' is not defined  no-undef```.


Should
```export default withRouter(Routes);```

be

```export default withRouter(Main)``` ?

Comment: Yes! I had a typo, already updated my answer it should say: ```export default withRouter(Main);```